# Need woocommerce function for getting cart list with items

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to add the list with added products from the woocommerce cart to a sidebar. Anybody know this method?

Comment: I believe there is a widget for this already provided by WooCommerce

Comment: Also for only getting the list with items added?

Comment: The documentation should answer all your questions: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-widgets/